# Google Glass - View captures gesture (swipe-down)

Tags: android, google-glass, gesture, google-gdk, user-interaction

I try to create an app for the Google Glass. The default swipe gesture goes default to the  menu of the glass. I have a Switch in my layout and the switch captures the gesture 'swipe-down', how can I fix this (not capturing gestures) so that the user can go to the menu with the default swipe down gesture.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't yet possible to override the `SWIPE_DOWN` gesture to do something other than the default behavior of returning to the previous activity. If this feature is important to you, please file a request in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: Looks like you can modify it by overriding the dispatchKeyEvent method.